# Create a list in a list from a file

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am trying to create a Python list in a list by reading a file.  The file contain the lines:

```
12, 'MWSTRES1', 'K1317055', 1
15, 'MWSTRES1', 'K1416241', 3
13, 'MWSTRES1', 'K1316235', 8
9, 'BTBITSPQ', 'J03016235', 3
1, 'PLAUSP01', 'K1316235', 2
2, 'VTNTBMOT', 'K1316237', 9
4, 'VTNTBMOT', 'K1316239', 13
```

**Code**:

```
combs = []
with open('file3', 'r') as f:
    result = [line.split(',')[:4] for line in f]
print(result)
print(sorted(result, key=lambda t: (t[0], t[1])))
```

**The generated list produced by the code is incorrect as shown**:

```
[['12', " 'MWSTRES1'", " 'K1317055'", ' 1\n'], ['15', " 'MWSTRES1'", " 'K1416241'", ' 3\n'], ['13', " 'MWSTRES1'", " 'K1316235'", ' 8\n'], ['9', " 'BTBITSPQ'", " 'J03016235'", ' 3\n'], ['1', " 'PLAUS
P01'", " 'K1316235'", ' 2\n'], ['2', " 'VTNTBMOT'", " 'K1316237'", ' 9\n'], ['4', " 'VTNTBMOT'", " 'K1316239'", ' 13']]
```

**I want the created list to look like this**:

```
[[12, 'MWSTRES1', 'K1317055', 1], [15, 'MWSTRES1', 'K1416241', 3], [13, 'MWSTRES1', 'K1316235', 8], [9, 'BTBITSPQ', 'J03016235', 3], [1, 'PLAUSP01', 'K1316235', 2], [2, 'VTNTBMOT', 'K1316237', 9], [4, 'VTNTBMOT', 'K1316239', 13]]
```

**The incorrect list is preventing me from obtaining the correct sorted output**:

```
[['1', " 'PLAUSP01'", " 'K1316235'", ' 2\n'], ['12', " 'MWSTRES1'", " 'K1317055'", ' 1\n'], ['13', " 'MWSTRES1'", " 'K1316235'", ' 8\n'], ['15', " 'MWSTRES1'", " 'K1416241'", ' 3\n'], ['2', " 'VTNTBMOT'", " 'K1316237'", ' 9\n'], ['4', " 'VTNTBMOT'", " 'K1316239'", ' 13'], ['9', " 'BTBITSPQ'", " 'J03016235'", ' 3\n']]
```

Can someone tell me how to create the correct list?

Comment: I hope no one is going to suggest `eval`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things you need to do to obtain the desired result.

```
def clean_line(line):
    # for the sake of completeness, remove surrounding blanks from all columns
    parts = [part.strip() for part in line.strip().split(',')[:4]]

    # first turn first and last columns to integers
    parts[0] = int(parts[0])
    parts[-1] = int(parts[-1])

    # single quotes need to be removed from the columns in the middle
    parts[1:-1] = [part.strip("'") for part in parts[1:-1]]
    return parts
```

In the end, your code should probably look something like this:

```
combs = []
with open('file3', 'r') as f:
    result = [clean_line(line) for line in f]
print(result)
print(sorted(result, key=lambda t: (t[0], t[1])))
```

Using this, list created from the file looks like this (formatting changed for the sake of readability):

```
[
    [12, 'MWSTRES1', 'K1317055', 1],
    [15, 'MWSTRES1', 'K1416241', 3],
    [13, 'MWSTRES1', 'K1316235', 8],
    [9, 'BTBITSPQ', 'J03016235', 3],
    [1, 'PLAUSP01', 'K1316235', 2],
    [2, 'VTNTBMOT', 'K1316237', 9],
    [4, 'VTNTBMOT', 'K1316239', 13]
]
```

Comment: `[part.replace("'", '')` just use `.strip("'")` ;-)

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thanks, I've completely forgot about that. ;)